# Property Inject in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inject

I have problem injecting a value to a bean using Spring MVC.

Here's my partial configuration of Spring:

```
<beans>
    <!-- Enable Annotation based configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- MailGun.org Authentication -->
    <bean class="com.example.something.util.MailSender">
        <property name="smtpHost" value="smtp.mailgun.org" />
        <property name="smtpUsername" value="USERNAME_HERE" />
        <property name="smtpPassWord" value="PASSWORD_HERE" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And here's the bean to inject:

```
package com.example.something.util;

@Component
public class MailSender {
    public void sendMail(String recipient, String subject, String text) {
        System.out.println(smtpHost);
    }

    @Autowired
    private String smtpHost;
}
```

To test this, I create a test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:test-spring-context.xml"})
public class MailSenderTest {
    @Test
    public void testSendMail() {
        MailSender sender = new MailSender();
        sender.sendMail("zjhzxhz@gmail.com", "Mail From MailGun", "This is a test mail");
    }
}
```

When I run this test case, I got an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.example.something.util.MailSender.smtpHost; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 43 more
```

What's wrong with it? Please help me. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `@Autowired` on `smtpHost`, it should be already populated if you get the `MailSender` bean from the Spring context. Which you don't, because instantiating it with `new MailSender()` bypasses Spring altogether. Instead you should use `context.getBean(MailSender.class)`.

Comment: But I don't think `context.getBean()` is an elegant implementation. Can I use an annotation here?

Comment: @HowardShieh use `@Autowired MailSender sender` and move it into a field for the test class rather than trying to initialize it in the method.

Comment: As @LuiggiMendoza said, you can use `@Autowired MailSender sender` here, because the test is running inside Spring context.